# How does one convert '+' to +, '*' to *, etc

Tags: c++, parsing, postfix-notation

I'm writing a function that reads a postfix expression in the form of a string and computes it accordingly.

Is there a simple way to convert the character of an arithmetic operator to the arithmetic operator itself in C++?

Comment: Depending on the number of operators you support, you might want to map each character to a functor such as `std::plus`.

Comment: I support '+', '-', '*', and '/'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that this is for the classic RPN programming exercise, the simplest solution is to use a `switch` statement:

```
char op = ...    
int lhs = ...
int rhs = ...
int res = 0;
switch(op) {
    case '+':
        res = lhs + rhs;
    break;
    case '-':
        res = lhs - rhs;
    break;
    case '*':
        res = lhs * rhs;
    break;
    case '/':
        res = lhs / rhs;
    break;
    case '%':
        res = lhs % rhs;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I wanted to make sure that there was no arithmetic casting already available in the language.

Comment: @DerekW: No, C++ doesn't include (in the standard) any sort of expression evaluator.  Operators in C++ are resolved by the compiler, and at runtime there is no concept of them.

Answer (score 10):

As @chris' comment says, you could create a map of characters to functors:

```
std::map<char, std::function<double(double,double)> operators{
  { '+', std::plus<double>{} },
  { '-', std::minus<double>{} },
  { '*', std::multiplies<double>{} },
  { '/', std::divides<double>{} }
};

double apply(double lhs, double rhs, char op)
{
  return operators[op](lhs, rhs);
}
```

This will throw `std::bad_function_call` if you call the function with a character that doesn't represent a known operator.

It will also create unwanted entries in the map for such unknown characters, to avoid that you could make it slightly more complciated:

```
double apply(double lhs, double rhs, char op)
{
  auto iter = operators.find(op);
  if (iter == operators.end())
    throw std::bad_function_call();
  return (*iter)(lhs, rhs);
}
```

(N.B. This uses C++11 features, but can pretty easily be translated to C++03, using `boost::function` or `std::tr1::function`)